# Pass text value for each empty field using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I created one XSLT with all kinds of validations etc. Now my client wants me to pass XXX for every blank value. There are lot of fields and I don't wan't to do it manually for each field. Can yo please help. Below is my XSLT

(Editing and simplifying my query)

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contract>
<customerName>foo</customerName>
<contractID />
<customerID>912</customerID>
<countryCode/>
<cityCode>7823</cityCode>
</contract>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="contract/customerName"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="contract/contractID"/>
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want the output as foo|XXX   (XXX for any blank field)

Comment: Without a sample of your input XML showing some of these "blank values" it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I've updated with XML now. Thanks

Comment: Here's a crucial question: will all the required fields always be there (even if empty), or can they be missing altogether)? -- P.S. it would be nice if you could reduce the example to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve]

Comment: I've put a modified and smaller example now. Pls take a look.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava **1.** You haven't answered my question. -- **2.** What's wrong with the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be using XSLT 2.0, I would suggest a radically different approach.

Here's a minimized example to produce the header part of your result:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="wd:Get_Workers_Response">
    <!--Defining Header-->
    <xsl:variable name="header-fields" select="
        wd:Request_Criteria/wd:Organization_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Organization_Reference_ID'],
        wd:Response_Results/wd:Total_Results,
        wd:Response_Results/wd:Total_Pages,
        format-date(current-date(), '[M01][D01][Y0001]')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(for $i in $header-fields return if (string($i)) then $i else 'XXX', '|')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <!--Ending Header-->

    <!--  ... continue for Employee Data and Footer ...  -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes a "field" can be empty, but not missing.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was able to use this code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(text()) = '']">
  <xsl:copy>XXX</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I added this but isn't working. Am I placing the code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Kirill Polishchuk answer,

use:

```
<!-- the not(*) is optional in the case, but ensure you're only hitting on leaf nodes -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and normalize-space(text()) = '']">
     <xsl:text>XXX</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and change all of your **<xsl:value-of ... />** to **<xsl:apply-templates .../>**
The default xsl template rules should pick up the nodes that contain text and output the values as normal.